# Getting null Refresh token

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using the google-api-java-client version 1.8-beta for oAuth2 authentication with Google accounts. Everything fine until I get the GoogleTokenResponse object, which has the access token but not refresh token.
To build the request url I user the following method :

```
...
    googleAuthenticationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID, callBackUrl, scopes).build();
...
```

When getting the request token I exchange it with an access token in this line :

```
...
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =  new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, request.getParameter(CODE_URL_PARAM), callBackUrl).execute();
...
```

The returned GoogleTokenResponse object does not contains the refresh token :

```
{"access_token":"ya29.AH..etc...9-Y","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

Could you please shed my light on this issue ? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When building the request Url, you should set the Access Type :

```
requestUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(googleClientId, callBackUrl, scopes)
    .setApprovalPrompt("force") // needed if user already granted permission
    .setAccessType("offline")
    .build();
```

As described in this [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2) setting this parameter is recommended :

> [...] We recommend that you explicitly set the access_type parameter
>   to offline because we anticipate that when the online value is
>   introduced, it will be as the default behavior. This could cause
>   unexpected changes in your application since it would affect the way
>   that your application is allowed to refresh access tokens. By
>   explicitly setting the parameter value to offline, you can avoid any
>   changes in your application's functionality. [...]

Comment: in GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder : Upgrade warning: prior to version 1.10 the default was {@code "offline"}. However, starting with version 1.10 it is {@code null}, which means {@code "online"} for web applications. To keep the prior behavior, you need to explicitly call {@code setAccessType("offline")}.

Comment: If what you (PapelPincel) write (taken from Google Developer page) were correct i'd say that is not sufficient to "Auto-refresh the token before it expires" (as https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ says). So how do i refresh access token in the background without ask an other time to User to make a new Authorization?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to PapelPincel's answer, I had to also force the approval prompt using the .Net 
release 1.8.1.970 to get the refresh token. eg

```cs
var authReq = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(GoogleAuthConsts.AuthorizationUrl)) { 
    RedirectUri = Callback, 
    ClientId = ClientId, 
    AccessType = "offline", 
    Scope = string.Join(" ", new[] { Scopes... }), 
    ApprovalPrompt = "force" 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting here from a Google search, I was not using the pure server side flow, so was getting the authorization token via javascript as in this [doc](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button), @PapelPincel answer was a hint for me.

You should add **data-accesstype="offline"** to your button as in the following snippet:

Example:

```
          <span
            data-accesstype="offline"
            class="g-signin"
            data-callback="signinCallback"
            data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
            data-redirecturi="postmessage"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
            data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
          </span>
```