# Connect to GMail with JavaMail API without enabling less secure access

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail, jakarta-mail

Is there any way to connect to GMail using the JavaMail API without enabling "Less secure access"?

Answer (score 3):

You must authenticate using OAuth2 to avoid turning on Less secure access.

Per very-hard-to-find docs

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol
- https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2

Example code:

```
Properties props = (Properties) System.getProperties().clone();
props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
// props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
// session.setDebug(true);

store = session.getStore("imaps");
String accessToken = getAccessToken(user, clientId, clientSecret);
store.connect(hostname, user, accessToken);
```

The next trick is getting that access token.

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#step-2:-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-2.0-server

Here's one you can use locally:

You'll first need to create an app at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and grab the client id and secret JSON

You can start up a local web server on any port and use the `http://localhost` redirect URL on any port (which needs to be added on the previously mentioned screen).

```
private static String getAccessToken(String emailAddress, String clientId, String clientSecret) throws Exception {
    NetHttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = Utils.getDefaultJsonFactory();

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory, new StringReader("{\n" +
            "  \"installed\": {\n" +
            "    \"client_id\": \"" + clientId + "\",\n" +
            "    \"client_secret\": \"" + clientSecret + "\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}"));
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Collections.singleton(GMAIL_SCOPE)).setAccessType("offline").build();

    AtomicReference<String> redirectUri = new AtomicReference<>();

    String authorizationCode = doRedirect("code=([^&$]+)", RE.wrapConsumer(p -> {
        redirectUri.set("http://localhost:" + p);
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(redirectUri.get()).toURI());
    }));

    // second redirect URL needs to be set and match the one on the newAuthorization flow but isn't actually used
    GoogleTokenResponse execute = flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode).setRedirectUri(redirectUri.get()).execute();

    String refreshToken = execute.getRefreshToken();
    String accessToken = execute.getAccessToken();

    return accessToken;
}

private static String doRedirect(String pattern, Consumer<Integer> portConsumer) {
    try {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0);
        portConsumer.accept(socket.getLocalPort());
        Socket connection = socket.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        PrintStream pout = new PrintStream(out);

        try {
            String request = in.readLine();
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(request);
            String response = "<html><body>Window can be closed now.</body></html>";
            pout.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            pout.println("Server: MyApp");
            pout.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            pout.println("Content-Length: " + response.length());
            pout.println();
            pout.println(response);
            pout.flush();
            if (matcher.find())
                return matcher.group(1);
            else
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not find match");
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while listening for local redirect", ex);
    }
}
```

Getting a refresh token and saving it for later is the best bet. Per [Getting null Refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294124/getting-null-refresh-token/10313235#10313235):

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = 
    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Collections.singleton(GMAIL_SCOPE))
        .setApprovalPrompt("force") // Needed only if you users didn't accept this earlier
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
```

Comment: How hard can the docs be to find if searching for "JavaMail OAuth2" takes you straight to them?

Comment: Until you know it's OAuth2 related, there's no indication that should be part of the search query; Without OAuth2 keyword, all the top results say to use username/password and that you might need to enable Less secure access